# Optimal condition for summability against $1/x$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in C([0,1])$ such that $f(0)=0$. Then the integral
$$
\int_0^1 \left| \frac{f(x)}{x} \right| dx
$$
is not defined in general. However, if we assume $f$ is Hölder continuous with any exponent $\alpha > 0$ then the above integral is always well defined. What are the optimal conditions on $f$ that guarantee that the above integral is finite? Would be enough to assume that $f$ is absolutely continuous in $[0,1]$?

Comment: Absolute continuity is not sufficient, consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{\log x}$ (with $f(0) = 0$). I don't know if there is any good criterion between "the integral is finite" and Hölder-continuity.

Answer (score 1):

The nearest non-tautological sufficient condition is [Dini continuity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini_continuity). It says that the modulus of continuity $\omega_f(t)$ satisfies $\int_0^1 \frac{\omega_f(t)}{t}\,dt<\infty$. Since $f(0)=0$, it follows that $|f(x)|\le \omega_f(x)$, hence 
$$
\int_0^1 \left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|\,dx \le \int_0^1  \frac{\omega_f(x)}{x} \,dx <\infty
$$

As Daniel Fischer noted in a comment, absolute continuity does not help. Absolute continuity is a qualitative property, which enables certain computations but does not directly translate into quantitative conclusions.